# p:SelectBooleanCheckbox : How to derive the boolean value when its state depends on the state of two entitys?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**What I have:** A datatable which contains properties of entities in direction x (e.g.: big, small...) and the entities itself in y direction. When the entities are created the user determines the properties and when I take a look at the datatable a booleanCheckbox should represent whether the entities contain the property or not. However I want to be able to change the properties in this datatable.

**Edit:** The entities (products) may have many categories and categories may have many products.

**Problem:**

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{product.hasCategory(cat)}">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="# {productController.remove(product, cat)}" update="propTabView:propForm:propTable"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

This does not work because the check-box expects a boolean only like 
`value="#{product.hasProperty}`
The result is a `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`

**What have I tried:** Display a boolean value as it is demanded by primefaces but its state is changed by a listener.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{productController.hasProperty}">
    <p:ajax event="???" listener="#{productController.change(product, cat)}"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**Problem:** I need to initialize the boolean value when the datatable is loaded.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to initialize the state of the checkbox when the datatable is loaded, depending on the entities in X and Y direction ?

**Question2:** How can I display a 2D SelectBooleanCheckBox where the state of the checkbox is derived from the states of the entity and the property ?

Thank You

Comment: You may need to define a `Map<Category, Boolean> myMap` in your controller. Then you can fill this map when the datatable is loaded. Eventually call `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{productController.myMap[cat]}"`to get the state.

Comment: @MathieuCastets, I would suggest exactly the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it !

Since I had two Entities (Product and Category) I have used 
`Map<Category, Map<Product, Boolean>>`

Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="propTable"
             value="#{productController.allProducts}"
             var="product"
             resizableColumns="true"
             reflow="true"
             tableStyle="width: auto">

    <p:column headerText="Artikel">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{product.name}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:columns value="#{categoryController.categories}" var="cat">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{cat.name}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{categoryController.map[cat][product]}">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{productController.update(product, cat)}"/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Controller:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    map = new HashMap<>();

    categories = categoryService.getCategories()
            .stream()
            .filter(c -> c.isForAll())
            .sorted((c1, c2) -> c1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Product> products = productService.getProducts();

    categories.stream().forEach(c -> 
        {
            Map<Product, Boolean> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
            products.stream().forEach(p -> 
            {
                valueMap.put(p,p.getCategories().contains(c));
            });
            map.put(c,valueMap);
        });
}
```